# VBA - Getting unique values from a column without using a split string

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm using the following code to save all unique values in a column of strings into an array, and then I get the amount of unique values by counting the length of the array.

```
Dim tmp As String
Dim prNumbers() As String
Dim arrLen As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim txt As String

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rngPR As Range
Set rngPR = Range("B2:B" & lastRow)

If Not rngPR Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In rngPR
        If (cell <> "") And (InStr(tmp, cell) = 0) Then
            tmp = tmp & cell & "|"
        End If
    Next cell
End If

If Len(tmp) > 0 Then tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)

prNumbers = Split(tmp, "|")

'Find the array length
arrLen = UBound(prNumbers) + 1
```

However, when I run this code, arrLen is a number smaller than the actual amount of unique entries in the column (I know this by doing a manual data check for unique entries.) Data in the column does not contain any "|" characters, only numbers.

What could the problem be? And is there an alternative way of getting the amount of unique entries into an array and determining its length?

Comment: http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/10/22/excel-udf-count-unique-distinct-values-in-a-large-dataset/

Answer (score 3):

This check probably is the problem:

```
(InStr(tmp, cell) = 0)
```

If e.g. a cell is `hello`, and a later cell is `ello`, it won't be included because `ello` is part of `hello` and thus the `tmp` string.

To go with your current method, change it to

```
(InStr(tmp, "|" & cell & "|") = 0)
```

and start with an initial `tmp = "|"`.

So if the current `tmp` is `|foo|hello|bar|`, you search it for `|ello|`, and get a 0.

---

A more straightforward way would be to use e.g. a collection, checking each new cell if it's already contained in the collection.

See http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CollectionsAndDictionaries.htm --> `KeyExistsInCollection`

Comment: Thanks for this. I now get more entries in my array, but still not all of the unique ones. I don't really see how that's possible! (I have 722 unique entries and get an array of only length 698). Also, should I remove the "|" at the the start again before the split?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Can you upload a sample workbook that shows the problem to a file hoster? And yes, the starting `"|"` should be removed before splitting, to avoid an empty array element.

Comment: @CornelVerster Maybe you have cells with the same value but different number format? You can try `cell.Text` instead of `cell`

Comment: @Andre: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2943689b68f84849df330c29610ed444

Comment: That's the range I'm looking at.

Comment: @Andre: Just saw it actually functions properly, there must be something else wrong :( Thanks for the help, I understand this function better now, and learned about collections!

Comment: @CornelVerster: cool. :) Because the `CountUniqueValues` function (using a collection) gets 697 too.